# java.lang.NullPointerException error when trying to locate a shadow element with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, shadow-root

I'm trying to locate a field to upload a file, but the element is inside a shadow-root

[image]

I tried the following code but I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` on `shadowRoot.findElement`:

```
private static WebElement getShadowRoot(WebDriver driver, WebElement shadowHost) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    return (WebElement) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", shadowHost);
}
    
public void uploadFileWithIncorrectBirthYear() throws TestingException {
    String url = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\files\\customer-upload-old-birth-year.xls";
    WebElement shadowHost = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cphContent_cifCustomerFile_fakeFileInput"));
    SearchContext shadowRoot = getShadowRoot(driver,shadowHost);
    WebElement shadowElement = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector("#file-upload-button"));
    shadowElement.sendKeys(url);
}
```

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Selenium 4.0+, there is a `.getShadowRoot()` method that takes care of this for you. You no longer need your own `getShadowRoot()` method and your code changes to the below.

```
public void uploadFileWithIncorrectBirthYear() throws TestingException {
    String url = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\files\\customer-upload-old-birth-year.xls";
    SearchContext shadowRoot = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cphContent_cifCustomerFile_fakeFileInput")).getShadowRoot();
    WebElement shadowElement = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector("#file-upload-button"));
    shadowElement.sendKeys(url);
}
```

Notice that the `.getShadowRoot()` method returns a `SearchContext` not a `WebElement`.

Comment: with the code you provided, i get       `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchShadowRootException: no such shadow root`

Comment: I'm just using the locators you provided. If you want updated locators, edit your question and post the relevant HTML as text, properly formatted.