# how to find exact xpath for the "button" web element in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, button, xpath, css-selectors

I have the following code for the button Element

[image]

I tried the below xpath ,unfortunately its not working .

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Agree to all']")).click();
```

Could you please help me to find the correct xpath for the Button Element?

Comment: `xpath` looks good to me. Please check if the element is inside an `iframe` or `shadow-root` element? If Url is public please attached to your question.

Comment: Hi ,its inside shadow-root

Comment: hope https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141681/does-anybody-know-how-to-identify-shadow-dom-web-elements-using-selenium-webdriv answers your question.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.NullPointerException error when trying to locate a shadow element with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75931152/java-lang-nullpointerexception-error-when-trying-to-locate-a-shadow-element-with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First identify the `Shadow-root` element and then identify the element inside it.

```
WebElement Shadowele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
    .executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//cmm-cookie-banner[@variant='B']")));
    
Shadowele.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Agree to all']")).click();
```